# Error Exporting SSIS Project From Integration Services Catalog

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm running SQL Server 2012 and am attempting to export a SSIS project from the Integration Services Catalogs as an ispac into a local SVN folder (using SSMS v17.9).

I'm seeing the following error message:

**Error: Value does not fall within the expected range.**

Any ideas what this error means and what the resolution this?

Cheers

Lins

Comment: I've investigated and found that exporting other projects from the catalog works. Trying to export my orig project in SSMS2012 throws a different error: "Unable to create the type with the name 'MSORA'". Which seems to relate to the Attunity drivers we're using.